# Hoffman and Kunze Linear Algebra Chapter 1.4 exercise 10 proof verification request

Tags: linear-algebra

**Exercise 10**
Let $R$ and $R'$ be $2\times3$ row-reduced echelon matrices and, both $RX=0$ and $R'X=0$ share the same solutions.
We need to show that $R=R'$.

*Proof*

Let $A$ be the matrix from which $R$ is obtained by finite amount of row operations. And let $B$ be the starting matrix of $R'$.
Let $Z=(z_1,z_2,z_3)$ be the solution set of $R$ and $R'$.
Theorem 5 states that every $m\times n $ matrix is row-equivalent to a row-reduced echelon matrix. Hence $Z$ is a solution set to $A$ and $B$ as well.
Since $A$ and $B$ share the same solutions, $A=B$, by theorem 1.
Hence, both $R$ and $R'$ are obtained from A by finite amount of row operations. Since row operations don't affect the solution set $Z$, $R=R'$.

**Theorem 1**
*Equivalent systems of linear equations have exactly the same solutions.*
**Theorem 5**
*Every $m \times n$ matrix $A$ is row-equivalent to a row-reduced echelon matrix.*

Comment: What is Theorem 1? Why can't it be directly applied to R, R'?

Comment: @Shahab It is other way around actually. Added the theorem in OP.

Comment: It does not work as in OP now.